# Heroku Godaddy site only loading using mobile data

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, godaddy, heroku

I have added the Heroku address using my Godaddy DNS account as a CNAME pointing to Heroku (DNS management>Records>Add). I have configured it with the name www and it uses the hostname that Heroku provided the target.

When I load my website it says 'server ip address could not be found'. However if I load the website using mobile data (as opposed to wifi), it loads and works. I am very confused and as this is the first time configuring a Heroku app with a custom domain, I am not sure if I am doing things right.

The domain used to be connected to a Wix site, but it has been detached. 
Here's a screenshot of my settings in Godaddy.

[image: Godaddy Screenshot]

Could anyone suggest what the issue is? Also when I look at the network calls, it says 'provisional-headers-show' and the 'User Agent' is labeled as Mozilla 5, iphone, AppleWebKit. They all seem to be mobile related. Maybe this is part of the issue, but I'm not sure what's causing it in the first place.

Comment: Have you tried loading the site using the full hostname that Heroku provided (starting with marine-bison...)?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yeah I tried just entering the dns target, but it just says 'there's nothing here yet', which is strange. Am I meant to append the name of my site onto the end or something?

Comment: the actual url is www.eastcottandburgess.com and for me only opens on mobile when using mobile data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS lookup for www.eastcottandburgess.com resolves to eastcott-burgess-deploy.herokuapp.com (it is a CNAME).

Using a globally distributed DNS checker (e.g. [dnschecker.org](https://dnschecker.org/#A/eastcott-burgess-deploy.herokuapp.com)) to lookup this host you will see that searches from different locations are returning different results in each location (some are actually quite similar). All of the results are IPs hosted by Amazon, probably on EC2.

[image: Part of dnschecker.org output]

This points to some geographic DNS and/or loadbalancing that will cause different results when using different networks. I suspect that you were seeing some old results on your normal broadband wifi connection because of ISP DNS caching and that this will resolve in due course.

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel. It looks like it was doing just that :)